# Empty page with logo after PrestaShop installation

Tags: installation, prestashop

My website is hosted on OVH (France), with one SQL database. 
I have installed manually PrestaShop from the GitHub folder.

After multiple attempts in installing PrestaShop, I finally reached to have it installed but since I choose to use the demo products (in the installation process and as I am new to PrestaShop), I think obtaining a white page with only the logo is surprising to me (see attachment).

I tried to print the errors switching to True the dev parameters from the file defines.inc.php, but nothing was printed.
Also, I see nothing in the console of the browser.

I suspect there is a conflict with the SQL database, but I don't know what to check.

Would you have any tracks to check what's wrong with my installation ?

Regards,
A&A

Comment: My questions is why did you install PS from GitHub? Default branch on GitHub is 1.6, which is NOT the current release version, but it is development version. It holds current changes that the team is working on but they are not released yet. Therefore, your problems may come from this if you clone 1.6 branch. Current release branch is master (1.6.0.9). Anyway, it's always best to download the .zip file from the official website.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Comment: I am having this same issue. This is the only evidence that someone else has run into this issue as well. @gskema I don't know about OP, but I used a github stable release "1.6.0.14", and not just the master. Still. I have this issue. I notice that the site seems to work. I can get to 404 pages, search pages, product pages, ect, although they're all extremely basic. I've replaced the theme with the prestashop.com download theme, but not change. I can't find any backoffice solution for how to display this content. Any help from anyone who sees this would be appreciated.